# CiviCRM WordPress Upgrade to 5.44.0 Error

Tags: wordpress, error, php

When upgrading I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Matrix\adjoint() (previously declared in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/markbaker/matrix/classes/src/Functions/adjoint.php:21) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.civiexportexcel/vendor/markbaker/matrix/classes/src/functions/adjoint.php on line 20

My guess is that it has to deal with the Civi Export As Excel extension which wasn't originally updated, but I have no idea. Is there a way to either update the extension manually if that is it or some way to just delete the problem?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update the export to excel extension: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civiexportexcel/-/blob/8d2dad043a79e40de79c5e32a6f94e8ca596aa01/CRM/CiviExportExcel/Utils.php#L8

You can upgrade it manually by just downloading the files (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civiexportexcel/-/archive/master/civiexportexcel-master.tar.gz) and replacing them in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.civiexportexcel

Comment: So, I want to delete all the files that are in the folder which match the names in the download, correct?

Comment: @demerit was absolutely correct! Appreciate all the help!